# Posting with jetty client gives a null Representation in restlet

Tags: java, jetty, restlet

I have been stuck a couple of hours on the following issue :

- I have a Jetty embedded server with a Restlet Application (MyApplication) bound to a Restlet ServerResource (MyResource) on one thread
- I have a Jetty client on the main thread, POSTing to the server with a dummy parameter p=toto
- I launch a navigator and browse to http://localhost:8082/model to get a html button that performs the same - at least expected to be - POST request (with p=toto)

I witness the following behavior:

- when the post is made through the Jetty client, the Representation given to MyResource.acceptItem is null. I can get the form and then the parameter only by calling getReference().getQueryAsForm();
- when the post is made through the navigator, the Representation given to MyResource.acceptItem is not null. I can get the Form by new Form(entity)

So my question is : what are the differences between the two POST requests that trigger these behaviors ?

Here is the output (we can see first the POST made by jetty, then a get from the navigator for the html form and finally the POST from the navigator

```
11:26:33.140 [main] INFO  org.sample.Sample - launching server on port 8082
2015-07-29 11:26:33.203:INFO::main: Logging initialized @359ms
2015-07-29 11:26:33.375:INFO:oejs.Server:Thread-0: jetty-9.2.7.v20150116
2015-07-29 11:26:33.437:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Thread-0: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@24cca73f{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2015-07-29 11:26:33.437:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:Thread-0: Started ServerConnector@746ab811{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8082}
2015-07-29 11:26:33.437:INFO:oejs.Server:Thread-0: Started @609ms
11:26:35.312 [main] INFO  org.sample.Sample - now posting
2015-07-29 11:26:35.687:INFO:/:qtp115342900-21: org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet-27a1f635: [Restlet] ServerServlet: component class is null
2015-07-29 11:26:35.734:INFO:/:qtp115342900-21: org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet-27a1f635: [Restlet] Attaching application: org.sample.MyApplication@6e47c1bf to URI: 
11:26:35.828 [qtp115342900-21] INFO  org.sample.Sample - proceeding POST
11:26:35.828 [qtp115342900-21] WARN  org.sample.Sample - entity is null !
11:26:35.828 [qtp115342900-21] INFO  org.sample.Sample - param p : toto
juil. 29, 2015 11:26:35 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2015-07-29    11:26:35    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8082    POST    /model  p=toto  204 0   0   63  http://localhost:8082   Jetty/9.2.7.v20150116   -
juil. 29, 2015 11:26:39 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2015-07-29    11:26:39    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8082    GET /model  -   200 172 0   0   http://localhost:8082   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0    -
11:26:43.515 [qtp115342900-22] INFO  org.sample.Sample - proceeding POST
11:26:43.515 [qtp115342900-22] INFO  org.sample.Sample - entity exists : [application/x-www-form-urlencoded,UTF-8]
11:26:43.515 [qtp115342900-22] INFO  org.sample.Sample - param p : toto
juil. 29, 2015 11:26:43 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2015-07-29    11:26:43    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8082    POST    /model  -   204 0   6   0   http://localhost:8082   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0    http://localhost:8082/model
```

Here is my project:
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>simple</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Jetty Server with Restlet Sample</name>

<properties>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <jetty.version>9.2.7.v20150116</jetty.version>
    <restlet.version>2.2.2</restlet.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

</properties>

<build>
    <!-- <finalName>atgm</finalName> -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>${restlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId>
        <version>${restlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

src/main/java/org/sample/Sample.java

```
package org.sample;

import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Sample {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sample.class);

    private static final int PORT=8082;

    private static Server server;


    public static void main (String []args) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("launching server on port "+PORT);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // now create the web server
                    server = new Server(PORT);

                    final ServletContextHandler servletContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
                    servletContext.setContextPath("/");
                    servletContext.setInitParameter("org.restlet.application", MyApplication.class.getName());
                    servletContext.addServlet(ServerServlet.class, "/*");
                    servletContext.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");

                    server.setHandler(servletContext);
                    server.start();
                    server.join();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOGGER.info("Failed to start server", ex);
                }
            }
        }.start();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.start();

        // waiting for the server to be online
        final int lapse = 2000;
        Thread.sleep(lapse);

        LOGGER.info("now posting");
        client.POST("http://localhost:"+PORT+"/model")
        .param("p", "toto")
        .send();
    }
}
```

src/main/java/org/sample/MyApplication.java

```
package org.sample;

import org.restlet.Application;
import org.restlet.Context;
import org.restlet.Restlet;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public MyApplication () {
        super();
    }

    public MyApplication (Context parentContext) {
        super(parentContext);
    }

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("/model", MyResource.class);
        return router;
    }
}
```

src/main/java/org/sample/MyResource.java

```
package org.sample;

import org.restlet.data.Form;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.Post;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyResource extends ServerResource {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sample.class);

    @Post
    public Representation acceptItem(Representation entity) throws Exception {
        Representation result = null;
        LOGGER.info("proceeding POST");
        Form form;
        if (null != entity) {
            LOGGER.info("entity exists : "+entity.toString());
            form = new Form(entity);
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn("entity is null !");
            form = getReference().getQueryAsForm();
        }
        LOGGER.info("param p : "+form.getFirstValue("p"));
        return result;
    }

    @Get("html")
    public String represent() {
        return "<html>"+
                "<head><script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js\"></script></head>"+
                "<body>"+
                "<button onclick=\"$.post('model',{p:'toto'});\">POST</button>"+
                "</form>"+
                "</body>"+
                "</html>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you made your POST request from the browser but here are some hints:

- `getQuery()` corresponds to the elements provided within the query string. What probably bothers you is that such data can be displayed as a form. In fact the class `Form` is similar to a form and doesn't correspond necessarily to the payload. So if you use URL like this: `http://localhost:8082/model?p=toto`, the parameter `p` will be present in query parameters
- the received representation (similar to `getEntity()`) corresponds to the payload. It can be a form if you use the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but generally it's not actually a form. In the first case, you can create a `Form` instance from the representation / entity. So if you use request like this, you will have an entry with name `p` in your representation / entity:

  ```
  POST /model
  Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

  p=toto
  ```

If you want to create such request with the Jetty client, you need to update your code like this:

```
Field p = new Field("p", "toto");
Fields fields = new Fields();
fields.put(p);

client.POST("http://localhost:"+PORT+"/model")
      .content(new FormContentProvider(fields))
      .send();
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for the highlights and the sample jetty code :)
Actually the POST from the browser is triggered from the HTML content that is got from the MyResource.represent.
It makes sense my client.POST call was too light to actually contain a payload.

Comment: basically, you made a confusion between the URL of the resource (that contains the query parameters) and the entity of the request. You should not think that query parameters and entity are similar. The URL is the identifier of the resource (even if it contains query parameters), whereas the entity of the request may be a representation of the state of the target resource (for example, when you PUT it), or the representation of any kind of state this resource is able to handle.